# Select an auto complete form

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to select the item from the auto complete list using Python and Selenium and for some reason I cannot seem to select the item that appears from the auto complete (MTG - MORTGAGE)--and for some reason WebdriverWait is not understood:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlwt


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver")
driver.get("https://www.okcc.online/")

time.sleep(2)

section_selector = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rod-menu-button"]')
section_selector.click()

time.sleep(2)

document_type = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rodDocTypeTxt"]').send_keys('MTG')

WebDriverWait.until(EC.visibility_of(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ui-id-10"]')))

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rodDocTypeTxt"]').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your element is present in the li so you need to handle that please check below code for your reference.

```
    driver.get("https://www.okcc.online/")
    driver.maximize_window()
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='rod-menu-button']"))).click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='rodDocTypeTxt']"))).send_keys('MD')
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id='ui-id-1']//li//div"))).click()
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: @DesertDeveloper : would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer and hit upvote button from your end.